# update table when finish session login in php

Tags: php, oracle11g

This is the other code statement in php, the opposite of my other question, it's about time to finish updating the log after finishing the session login

```
<?php 
    include ('connect.php');/*to connect to database with oracle 11g*/

    session_start();
    $_SESSION = array();

    $email = $_SESSION["EMAIL_USER"];
    $passw = $_SESSION["PASS_USER"];

    $query = "UPDATE LOGIN SET OUT_TIME_LOGIN = LOCALTIMESTAMP WHERE EMAIL_USER = '$email' AND PASS_USER = '$passw';";
    $sid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
    $result = oci_execute($sid);
    $dbarray = oci_fetch_array($sid);

    unset ($_SESSION);

    if(ini_get("session.use_cookies")){
       $params = session_get_cookie_params();
       setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 50000,
       $params["path"], $params["domain"],
       $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]);
    }

    session_destroy();
    session_commit();
    /**/
    header("location: ../menu.html");
    ?>
```

when I finish the logon session, was supposed to update the table with the login time to exit to exemples: `LOCALTIMESTAMP where email_user = '$email';`

and when I try log out, I received error

> Undefined index: EMAIL_USER AND PASS_USER

and in my other question, [PHP - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31600649/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file), I re-edited the codes 
and I made this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE user_email = '$email' AND user_pass= '$passw'";
$sid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
$result = oci_execute($sid);
$dbarray = oci_fetch_array($sid);

if (($dbarray["user_email"] == $email) && ($dbarray["user_pass"] == $passw)) {
     session_start();
     $_SESSION["user_email"] = $email;
     $_SESSION["user_pass"]  = $passw;
            switch ($dbarray["type_user_id"]) {
                case 1:
                    header("Location: admin.php");
                    break;
                default:
                    echo "<script> alert('ERROR:'); history.back() </script>";
                    exit;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

and now I intend to do the opposite to get the email and password of the online session
any suggestion?

Comment: in both codes you are using different session `$_SESSION["EMAIL_USER"]; ` and below code '$_SESSION["user_email"]' if you change this `$_SESSION["EMAIL_USER"]; ` to this '$_SESSION["user_email"]' and so as this `$_SESSION["PASS_USER"];` to this `$_SESSION["user_pass"];` it may resolve the problem

Comment: by the way you also don''t need this `$_SESSION = array();`

Comment: I tried and worked  but the table login is not update the OUT_TIME_LOGIN

Comment: just `OUT_TIME_LOGIN` not updating or its blank or there is nothing when you update?

Comment: will add this to answer but there is another problem in your update query

Comment: is worked but know I think the problem is update query and I change all email_user and pass_user to user_email and user_pass

Comment: yeah i sorted that in answer check answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at both of the codes, I see following errors

In First code $_SESSION variables are

```
$email = $_SESSION["EMAIL_USER"];
$passw = $_SESSION["PASS_USER"];
```

But in 2nd code when you are fetching data from database and loading variables to Session

```
 $_SESSION["user_email"] = $email;
 $_SESSION["user_pass"]  = $passw;
```

So change these

```
$email = $_SESSION["EMAIL_USER"];
$passw = $_SESSION["PASS_USER"];
```

To this

```
$email = $_SESSION["user_email"];
$passw = $_SESSION["user_pass"];
```

This will resolve your following error

> Undefined index: EMAIL_USER AND PASS_USER

and in your first code you don't need `$_SESSION = array();`

In your 2nd code you are fetching data with following query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE user_email = '$email' AND user_pass= '$passw'";
```

and in your first code you are updating data with following query

```
$query = "UPDATE LOGIN SET OUT_TIME_LOGIN = LOCALTIMESTAMP WHERE EMAIL_USER = '$email' AND PASS_USER = '$passw';";
```

change you update query because you are referring to right table but wrong table and col names

```
$query = "UPDATE login SET OUT_TIME_LOGIN = LOCALTIMESTAMP WHERE user_email = '$email' AND user_pass = '$passw';";
//you need to check `OUT_TIME_LOGIN` col name in your database too i m sure its wrong too
```

Also you have to change this
    `LOCALTIMESTAMP`
To this, first define `$datetime`

```
$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

so final update query will be like

```
$query = "UPDATE login SET out_time_login = '$datetime' WHERE user_email = '$email' AND user_pass = '$passw';";
```

and you asked "get the email and password of the online session"

In your PHP code you can

```
echo $_SESSION["user_email"];
echo $_SESSION["user_pass"];
```

Or in HTML

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["user_email"];?>">
<input type="text" name="pass" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["user_pass"];?>">
```

Comment: thanks @shehary, everything is worked and just the table login don´t update the OUT_TIME_LOGIN as I intended to do

Comment: check the answer i explained that part too :) also make sure `OUT_TIME_LOGIN` is the right col name, no margin of error in spellings or upper or lower case letters, what if its like `out_time_login`

Comment: $localtime = localtime();, dont update the table

Comment: paste your query here and confirm that OUT_TIME_LOGIN is right col name on login table?

Comment: what's your time zone? I again update the answer, the update query part, check and try again.

Comment: I tried to create an user with this date so everythig is worked, and I made tried in sql developer this `SELECT * FROM LOGIN WHERE USER_EMAIL = 'user@email.pt' AND USER_PASS = '123456';

UPDATE LOGIN SET TIME_OUT_LOGIN = LOCALTIMESTAMP WHERE USER_EMAIL = 'user@email.pt' AND USER_PASS = '123456'; ` and the table login update normal but with the php codes with squery don´t do nothing

Comment: ok i think its in Europe, forgive me my lack of knowledge, you need to add this line in before `session_start` `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');` and then echo $datetime; and see if you get your local time

Comment: in the beginning, I made in sql developer `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE         ='PORTUGUESE';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY        = 'PORTUGAL';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT      = 'DD/MM/YYYY';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIME_FORMAT      = 'HH24:MI:SS';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'HH24:MI:SS';`

Comment: all is worked, just `$query`don´t update te table with the session opened

Comment: ok so problem resolved, all of them ?

Comment: Can a paste your  query u mentioned in comment with u create users

Comment: the user is create in same same like login I used insert all, the codes is this in this link http://pastebin.com/713btMUG

Comment: I dont see `TIME_OUT_LOGIN` in the pastebin so either it  doesnot exist in login table or its name is different

Comment: see here I update the codes, http://pastebin.com/BG98vYzx, `TIME_OUT_LOGIN` and `DATE_LOGIN`beginnig `NULL` to I update later

Comment: its not `TIME_OUT_LOGIN` it is `out_time_login` there is very very very big difference, and also its not `DATE_LOGIN` its `date_login`, you have to be Careful with this, if table name is `login` then in your query must be `login` you cant use `Login` or `LOGIN` it will not do anything

Comment: last update http://pastebin.com/DUdFKCM7, @shehary, thanks for your help and for your time, it is taking and I go to school maybe later we can solve here in Portugal, in Europe, it's day and to go to school, is well and thanks again

Comment: no problem man, have nice day at school.

Comment: I changed all and test and still in the same and I´m tired maybe later, maybe my teacher can help me, your solution is correct, I don´t understand why the codes  worked just just does not do anything to update the login table

Comment: I've been analyzing the code more closely and I managed to solve the problem, your answer was correct, I do not analyzed more thoroughly the code, but has worked and thank again